# How to check for duplicate entries in a gridview and prevent them

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am relatively new to programming and I am having trouble figuring out how to detect and prevent a user from entering in duplicate values into a gridview I have containing multiple controls.  Currently I am using a foreach loop to loop through the controls that contain the values that cannot be duplicates and it works for the most part, however when I edit the first record in a table and try to "update" the record, even if I haven't changed any values, I receive a null reference exception and I don't know why.  I have attached any pertinent code below and would appreciate any and all help to come to a solution.

Please excuse the long post, I am trying to be as thorough as possible without adding irrelevant information.

To start I have a grid view with a series of controls in it allowing a user to enter information into our database. The gridview and the relevant controls can be seen below.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server"
        EmptyDataText="No Miscellaneous" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" DataKeyNames="RecID"
        ShowFooter="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource7" Width="95%"
        OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound" >

    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMiscEquipmentNew" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourcePartEquipment" DataValueField="RecID"
            DataTextField="EquipmentPart" AppendDataBoundItems="True" AutoPostBack="True" Width="220px" Height="20px" style="margin-left: 70px;" >
            <asp:ListItem Value="0">---SELECT---</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMiscNew" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceMisc" DataValueField="RecID" DataTextField="Description"
            AppendDataBoundItems="true" Width="220px" Height="20px" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlMiscNew_SelectedIndexChanged"
            OnDataBound="ddlMiscNew_DataBinding">
            <asp:ListItem Value="0">---SELECT---</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtMiscQuantityNew" runat="server" Width="95px" Style="margin-left: 68px;" AutoPostBack="True" OnTextChanged="txtMiscQuantityNew_TextChanged" />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtMiscCostNew" runat="server" Width="95px" Text="0" ReadOnly="True" />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtMiscRequestedNew" runat="server" Width="95px" Text="0" ReadOnly="True" />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtMiscTaxNew" runat="server" Width="95px" Text="0" />
        <asp:Button ID="InsertDetail" runat="server" CommandName="InsertDetail" Height="25px" Text="Add Detail" Width="85px" UseSubmitBehavior="True" />
    </EmptyDataTemplate>

    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" FooterText="Add -->" ShowDeleteButton="true" HeaderStyle-Width="70px" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="RecID" HeaderText="RecID" SortExpression="RecID" ReadOnly="True" Visible="False" />

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Miscellaneous" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblMiscEquipmentAdd" Text='<%# Bind("EquipmentType") %>' runat="server" Width="220px" />
                    <asp:Label ID="lblMiscDescriptionAdd" Text='<%# Bind("MiscDescription") %>' runat="server" Width="220px" />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMiscEquipmentEdit" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourcePartEquipment" DataValueField="RecID" DataTextField="EquipmentPart" SelectedValue='<%# Eval("EquipmentID") %>'
                        AppendDataBoundItems="True" AutoPostBack="True" Width="220px" Height="20px">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="0">---SELECT---</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMiscEdit" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceMisc" DataValueField="RecID" DataTextField="Description" SelectedValue='<%# Eval("MiscType") %>' AppendDataBoundItems="True" Width="220px" Height="20px" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlMiscEdit_SelectedIndexChanged">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="0">---SELECT---</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMiscEquipmentInsert" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourcePartEquipment" DataValueField="RecID" DataTextField="EquipmentPart"
                        AppendDataBoundItems="True" Width="220px" Height="20px" style="margin-left: 29px;">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="0">---SELECT---</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMiscInsert" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceMisc" DataValueField="RecID" DataTextField="Description" AppendDataBoundItems="True" Width="220px" Height="20px" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlMiscInsert_SelectedIndexChanged">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="0">---SELECT---</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

There are more controls in the gridview but these are where the problem lies.  As you can see there are a number of drop down lists and textboxes, the controls in question are the drop down list "ddlMiscEdit" in the edit item template and the label "lblMiscDescriptionAdd". When the user makes a selection in the aforementioned ddl and proceeds to hit the insert detail button at the end of each row it adds the values to the gridview, and in turn they are added to my database through a row command event. This works as intended, the problem I run into is when a user trys to edit the first row of the gridview and changes the value for ddlMiscEdit, it triggers a null reference exception for the label lblMiscDescriptionAdd.

In order to detect duplicates I have a For Each loop in the selectedIndexChanged event for the ddlMiscEdit drop down as shown below.

```
 For Each row In GridView2.Rows
        Dim miscdescription As Label = (CType(row.FindControl("lblMiscDescriptionAdd"), Label))
        If miscdescription.Text = ddlMiscEdit.SelectedItem.Text Then
            lblErrorMisc.Text = "Miscellaneous items can only be claimed once"
            Return
        Else
            lblErrorMisc.Text = ""
            Return
        End If
    Next
```

I am thinking this exception has to do with the fact that when the user clicks edit it activates the drop down list and hides the label, thus when it comes to the loop "lblMiscDescriptionAdd" doesn't exist in that specific context.

I have also tried putting the foreach loop in the row command event for the gridview in the "Update" commandName section, which leads to the same issue but in a different place.  When this loop is in the Update section mentioned above, instead of receiving this exception on the first record of the gridview I receive it in the second/third/fourth record, basically everything except the first record.

I use that same foreach loop in the InsertDetail command and it works as intended preventing duplicate values from being entered into the gridview, the exception only appears when I am trying to edit a given row depending on where I put the loop.

I apologize for the long post but I don't really know how to simplify my issue beyond what I have done here.  I am pretty new to programming so I don't know if I could go about doing this in a better/more efficient manner, but any help/critiques would be greatly appreciated as I am at a loss as to how to fix this problem.  Thank you in advance for any effort on your part for helping me solve this.

Comment: do you really need to have in-line editing? I mean, you could display the rows, and when you click edit, then you pop up a dialog, or even hide the gv, display the information in a form like display with a save/cancel/delete button. I suggest this kind of "work" flow, since then when you hit save, you can run your test/check code with far greater ease. So, perhaps you setup editing like this working example here (in this example, the edit button pops a form: http://www.kallal.ca/Website11/WebForm2

Comment: Use the gridview to make a primary key selection (gridview need only display enough information to make a unique selection)  Then pass that to a `FormView` or even a `DetailsView` to do elaborate data checking.  It'll be far easier than what you are trying to force a Gridview to do.

Comment: You can also do a certain amount of data validation directly via the data source using tools like unique indexes/constraints, although possibly might be considered the ambulance at the bottom of the cliff

Comment: see my example below - I show a check for duplicate in action with a GV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a long story short?

Don't try and process the GV.What happens if other users are adding data. You may well not have re-loaded the grid with updated data.

In your save code for the one record, simple hit/pull/query the main database and check for the record. That way you not messing around all day trying to process and pull values out of the GV.

Always try to think in terms of data management, not trying to use the actual GV as some kind of database - it only for display, and selecting the data to edit, but to check for duplicates, then simple query the database for that information and check if such records already exist.

For example, I have a simple GV with some hotels. (that working example you can try here: http://www.kallal.ca/Website11/WebForm2 ).

So, I have a add button to allow adding of a new reocrd. And I also have a "save" button. It would be in that save button that I simple add code to check say if the hotel name already exists in the database, and not allow that addition.

And what happens with edits? If a user edits existing, and again changes a name to some existing value, then again you have to deal with code to test/check that case.

So, be it adding, or editing, you need to check for that duplicate.

The code thus becomes rather simple. My save button code thus with code to check for the hotel already existing could/would look/work like this:

```
Protected Sub cmdSave_ServerClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    ' check for dupliate hotel name when saving or adding new reocrd.
    Dim intPK As Integer = ViewState("PK")

    Dim strSQL As String =
        "SELECT HotelName FROM tblHotelsA 
        WHERE HotelName = @HotelName AND ID <> @ID"

    Dim cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL)
    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@HotelName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtHotel.Text
    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = intPK
    Dim rstDataCheck As DataTable = MyrstP(cmdSQL)
    If rstDataCheck.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        ' we have a duplicate hotel, don't allow adding!
        ' code here to inform user that this is a duplicate
        ' hotel and you can't add it.
        Me.MyCustomMessage.InnerText = "Can't add this hotel - duplicate"
        Exit Sub

    End If

    ' code here to save the edit back to database
    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA WHERE ID = " & intPK

    Using conn = New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)
        Using cmdSQL2 = New SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)
            conn.Open()
            Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL2)
            Dim daU As New SqlCommandBuilder(da)

            Dim rstData As New DataTable
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL2.ExecuteReader)

            With rstData.Rows(0)

                .Item("HotelName") = txtHotel.Text
                .Item("FirstName") = tFN.Text
                .Item("LastName") = tLN.Text
                .Item("City") = tCity.Text
                .Item("Province") = tProvince.Text
                .Item("Description") = txtNotes.Text
                .Item("Active") = chkActive.Checked
                .Item("Balcony") = chkBalcony.Checked
                .Item("Smoking") = chkSmoking.Checked
            End With

            da.Update(rstData)

        End Using
    End Using

    LoadGrid()   ' refrsh grid to show any new edits

    ShowGrid(True)  ' hide edit area, show grid

End Sub
```

So, in action, then the above will look like this.

We will edit the record and try to create a duplicate.

[image]